# Adding MarkerOptions Object to the DirectionsRenderer in google API

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, google-maps-markers, map-directions

So I want to change the look of the markers on the google maps direction service and can't figure out how. According to Google developers I can use MarkerOptions to specify what I want the markers to look like. Can someone tell/show me how to add use the MarkerOptions object within directions renderer?

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates what you have tried that you thought should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can check this link [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Shreerang/kEcgc/light/), you should create the marker object with an image.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: image,
            title: beach[0],
            zIndex: beach[3]
        });
  }
```

for the record this is not written by me I just found it online.